# $\sqrt{1^{1.5}}=1$ why?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

ok, so I know that $\sqrt{{1}^{1.5}}=1$ but can anyone tell me why it equals $1$? what is it called? I want to understand and I'm a visual learner does it have a video?

Comment: This question is about basic arithmetic.  That an expression or calculation resembling this occurs in some book on electromagnetism is almost entirely irrelevant and nothing involved in the content of the question has anything to do with the specific nuances associated with questions specifically about electro-magnetism.  As such, mentioning it in the title and the tags is unnecessary.

Comment: $1$ to the power of *any value* is just $1$ (even when raised to the power of $0$). Also, $\sqrt{1}=1$. So, this means (or implies) what exactly? **P.S.** Because of this special property of $1$, it is commonly referred to as the *multiplica-tive identity* (with $0$ being the *additive identity*).

Answer (score 3):

Forgetting all the branching business of complex analysis, we can write it equivalently as $1^{3/4}$. Since $1^{3}=1$, we get $1^{1/4}$. So we want to solve the equation $1^{1/4}=x$. This is equivalent to $x^4=1$ and we know that 1 satisfies it.

I'm not sure what "it" is in "what is it called".

Answer (score 2):

In this problem $\sqrt{1^{1.5}}$ can be written as $1^\frac{1.5}{2}$. So, note that $1^n$ (where n= real numbers) is always $1$.

$1$ power any number is always $ 1 $.

Answer (score 2):

The statement comes down to understanding that 1 to any power is 1.  If you want a visual explanation for this, you can start with the definition of exponent.
First,
$$a^n = \overbrace{a \times a \times a \times \cdots \times  a}^{n \ times}.$$

This is true for any whole number $n$.  Thus $$1^3 = 1 \times 1 \times 1 = 1.$$

The square root of $1$ is $1$ from the fact that $1 \times 1 = 1$ in the same way that the square root of $4$ is $2$ from the fact that $2 \times 2 = 4.$

Next 
$a^{b/c}$ is defined to be $\sqrt[c]{a^b}$.  Thus $$1^{3/2} = \sqrt[2]{1^3} = \sqrt[2]{1} = 1.$$

Finally $$\sqrt{1^{1.5}} = \sqrt{1^{3/2}}= \sqrt{1} = 1.$$